# How to send one view controller values to another view controller table view in swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have three view controllers like below

[Add address Table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFZHt.png) this is AddAddressViewcontroller, if i select addaddress button it goes to [profileviewcontroller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikYyY.png) if i tap continue it goes to [ZoomMapviewcontroller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATsph.png) here is i confirm then i need to show that below label text in  `AddAddressViewcontroller` **Add address Table view** how to do that.

**ZoomMapviewcontroller code:**

```
protocol DataEnteredDelegate: class {
func userDidEnterInformation(info: DataEnteredModelSave)
}

class NewZoomAddressViewController: UIViewController {
weak var delegate: DataEnteredDelegate? = nil

var zipName: String?
var localityName: String?
var sublocalityName: String?

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var addressLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
@IBAction func confirmBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddAddressViewController") as! AddAddressViewController
   guard
        let zipName = zipName,
        let sublocalityName = sublocalityName,
        let localityName = localityName
        else { return }
    let enteredData = DataEnteredModelSave(pinCode: zipName, streetField: sublocalityName, cityField: localityName)
    delegate?.userDidEnterInformation(info: enteredData)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)

}
}
```

**here how to send zipName, locality, subLocality valuew to Addaddressviewcontroller tableview**

***AddAddressViewcontroller*** code:

```
 class AddAddressViewController: UIViewController,DataEnteredDelegate {
@IBOutlet var addressEDITTableview: UITableView!

var city: String?
var pincode: String?
var locality: String?

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: EditAddressTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EditAddressTableViewCell") as! EditAddressTableViewCell
    cell.nameHeader.text = "header"
    cell.addressLabel.text = "\(city!) \(pincode!) \(locality!)" // here i need ZoomMapviewcontroller valuew in row

}
}
```

please help me with code, i got stuck here from long time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 approaches here..

First method is assuming you have correctly set the DataEnteredDelegate in the AddAddressViewController. Your mistake here is, you are calling a delegate method in an already existing AddAddressViewcontroller instance in the navigationController stack and pushing a new AddAddressViewcontroller into that stack again.

Second method, if you really want to push (which is unnecessary as per me) a new AddAddressViewController instance to the navigationController stack again.

**First approach** :-
You've already an AddAddressViewController instance in your navigationController stack. So you just need to pop back to that view controller. So your confirmBtn action in NewZoomAddressViewController will be :-

```
@IBAction func confirmBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    guard
        let zipName = zipName,
        let sublocalityName = sublocalityName,
        let localityName = localityName
    else { return }

    if let viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
        for aViewController in viewControllers {
            if aViewController.isKind(of: AddAddressViewController.self) {
                let addAddressVC = aViewController as? AddAddressViewController
                let enteredData = DataEnteredModelSave(pinCode: zipName, streetField: sublocalityName, cityField: localityName)
                delegate?.userDidEnterInformation(info: enteredData)
                self.navigationController?.popToViewController(aViewController, animated: true)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Second Approach** :- In this case there is no need for delegate. You can directly pass the zipName, sublocalityName and localityName  to the new AddAddressViewController.

```
@IBAction func confirmBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddAddressViewController") as! AddAddressViewController
    guard
        let zipName = zipName,
        let sublocalityName = sublocalityName,
        let localityName = localityName
        else { return }
    viewController.city = localityName
    viewController.pincode = zipName
    viewController.locality = localityName
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: thank you, how can i show `enteredData ` in `cell.addressLabel.text` pls help

Comment: Edited. You can directly pass the zipName, sublocalityName and localityName to the new AddAddressViewController.

Comment: in `AddAddressViewController ` how to show `numberOfRowsInSection` return ??

Comment: for eg if i return 2.. it shows two times same value...... and if i enter new address the old address is not coming

Comment: please do help to add `numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: You have to try my first approach. Because right now what you are doing is keep on creating the AddAddressViewController instance every time and all these instances have only one set of data, which they get at the time of creation. You need to maintain a DataEnteredModelSave array in AddAddressViewController and update that with delegate every time confirm button is pressed.

Comment: You are missing a lot of basic concepts like class, struct, instances, delegate etc. You need to first understand these concepts thoroughly. Then you yourself will understand what exactly is the problem. Explaining all these are beyond the scope of a stack overflow answer.

Comment: pls u can see this question..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62132321/how-can-i-update-the-numberofrowsinsection-and-how-do-i-show-all-added-values-in/62132594?noredirect=1#comment109911742_62132594

Comment: here how to add all added rows in tableview in addaddreessVC