# How can I update the numberOfRowsInSection and how do I show all added values in this tableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview, row

I am trying to send values from one view controller - `NewZoomAddressViewController` to another one - `Add_EditAddressViewController`. I am sending the values to an array in the second view controller (`addressArray`).

Here is the first view controller:

```
class NewZoomAddressViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var addressLabel: UILabel!
var addressArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("in Zoom map VC")
    mapView.delegate = self
    addressLabel.text = "\(self.sublocalityName!) \(localityName!) \(self.zipName!)"

}
@IBAction func confirmBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Add_EditAddressViewController") as! Add_EditAddressViewController
    addressArray.append("\(sublocalityName ?? "") \(zipName ?? "") \(localityName ?? "")")
    viewController.addressArray = addressArray
    navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}
}
```

Then here I am adding values to `addressArray` from `NewZoomAddressViewController` like below:

```
class Add_EditAddressViewController: UIViewController,DataEnteredDelegate {
@IBOutlet var addressEDITTableview: UITableView!

  var addressArray = [String]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addressEDITTableview.register(UINib(nibName: "EditAddressTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "EditAddressTableViewCell")
    addressEDITTableview.reloadData()

}
}
extension Add_EditAddressViewController : UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return addressArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: EditAddressTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EditAddressTableViewCell") as! EditAddressTableViewCell
    cell.nameHeader.text = "header"
    cell.addressLabel.text = addressArray[indexPath.row]//"\(city) \(pincode) \(locality)"

    return cell
}
}
```

However, in the table view I am only getting one row. The first time, the single row is okay, but if I add another address - the row is replaced with the new address, and I am no longer getting the old address. How do I show all of the added addresses in the table view?

Comment: `addressArray` gets deallocated everytime you move back to the screen. You should declare it in `Add_EditAddressViewController ` and append the data there only then send it to `otherviewcontroller `

Answer (score 1):

`addressArray` gets deallocated everytime you move back to the screen. You should declare it in `Add_EditAddressViewController` and append the data there only then send it to `otherviewcontroller`

```
  var addressArray : [String] = []

  @IBAction func confirmBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Add_EditAddressViewController") as! Add_EditAddressViewController;
    self.addressArray.append("\(sublocalityName ?? "") \(zipName ?? "") \(localityName ?? "")")
    vc.addressArray = self.addressArray
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true);

}
```

And then in your `otherViewController`

```
var addressArray : [String] = [] { 
      didSet { 
          self.addressEDITTableview.reloadData()
      }
 }
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  extension Add_EditAddressViewController : UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return addressArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: EditAddressTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EditAddressTableViewCell") as! EditAddressTableViewCell
    cell.nameHeader.text = "header"
    cell.addressLabel.text = addressArray[indexPath.row]
  return cell
 }
 }
```

Comment: here  `self.tableView.reloadData()` error : Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: pls do help... got stuck here from long time

Comment: @iPhoneIOS try now .

Comment: but where did you did `addressEDITTableview.reloadData()`

Comment: here  self.addressEDITTableview.reloadData():
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: but in `confirmBtn` array values are there

Comment: @iPhoneIOS you have not connected your tableView with this outlet i guess.

Comment: actually one row is coming... if i go back to `NewZoomAddressViewController ` and add anoter value to `addressArray` here the new value replacing in old value and showing only one row in tableview ....... but i need how many times i add new address that many row in tableview

Comment: do you know why tableview not updating with new row in my post

Comment: `@IBOutlet var addressEDITTableview: UITableView!` change it to `@IBOutlet weak var addressEDITTableview: UITableView! and then try
`

Comment: I have tried all your answers but couldn't achieve, if you got time please try to go through my only this question related code in gitgub : https://github.com/SwiftSamples/ContactProject .. and try to help

Answer (score 1):

Update: Try out the following code on your Xcode-playground and play around with it to see how it works and try to implement the same logic in your code.

```swift
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var array = [String]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let button = UIButton(type: .contactAdd)
        button.center = view.center
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(add), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)
    }
    @objc func add() {
        array.append("New element \(array.count)")
        let controller = TableViewController()
        controller.array = array
        present(controller, animated: true)
    }
}
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var array = [String]()
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        array.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ViewController())
```

Store the array outside the function scope and keep adding new elements to the same array instead of a new instance.

In InitialViewController with button action:

```swift
var addressArray = [String]()

@IBAction func confirmBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Add_EditAddressViewController") as! Add_EditAddressViewController
    addressArray.append("\(sublocalityName ?? "") \(zipName ?? "") \(localityName ?? "")")
    viewController.addressArray = addressArray
    navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

In Add_EditAddressViewController:

```swift
class Add_EditAddressViewController: UIViewController {
    var addressArray = [String]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addressEDITTableview.reloadData()
    }
}

extension Add_EditAddressViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return addressArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: EditAddressTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EditAddressTableViewCell") as! EditAddressTableViewCell
        cell.nameHeader.text = "header"
        cell.addressLabel.text = addressArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: same like mine its coming... only one row is loading.. if i add another address not adding in tableview

Comment: Check once again. I forgot `append` part.

Comment: Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'addressArray'

Comment: Check again. You need to cast it.

Comment: in Add_EditAddressViewController  `var addressArray = [String]()` taken like this and indidload did `tableview.reloaddata()` and in `cellfor row: cell.addressLabel.text = addressArray[indexPath.row]`  and `numberofrows return addressArray.count`. then only one row is adding new value replace with oldvalue in tableview

Comment: In `viewDidLoad` only do reload, remove everything else.

Comment: yes in viewDidLoad only doing tableview.reloaddata().. still all new value replacing with old vale

Comment: how many times i add new address only one row is coming.. new value replacing in that same row may i know where i am wrong :(

Comment: I think you are updating the array somewhere else that is not shown in the question.

Comment: see i have updated my total code in my question according to your answer.. let me know where i am wrong

Comment: all the time one row is coming.. not adding new address row

Comment: I've posted a playground example for you, check it out.

Comment: hello if i print `viewController.addressArray` before navigate to ZoomMapVC if i add 2nd time address then also only new value adding to `addressArray` not coming previous address in array